# HTML and Javascript Client-Side Authentication

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, client-side

I am creating a client-side verification (Yes, this seems to serve no purpose but it does). The problem is that I am not so good with js and my code don't work.

**•What I'm trying to accomplish:**

User types "ABCD" as a password and clicks on submit.
Javascript checks if password is "ABCD" and if so, it continues, if not, it displays an error message.

**• The Code:**

HTML :

```
<div class="login">
  <div class="login__check"></div>
  <div class="login__form">
    <div class="login__row">
      <svg class="login__icon pass svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M0,20 20,20 20,8 0,8z M10,13 10,16z M4,8 a6,8 0 0,1 12,0" />
      </svg>
      <input type="password" class="login__input pass" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="login__submit">Sign in</button>
    <p class="login__signup">Don't have an account? &nbsp;<a>Sign up</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
   $(document).on("click", ".login__submit", function (e) {

    var password = "ABCD";
    //this is your password input box
    if ($('input[pass] .login__input').val() == password) {
        if (animating)
            return;
        animating = true;
        var that = this;
        ripple($(that), e);
        $(that).addClass("processing");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(that).addClass("success");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $app.show();
                $app.css("top");
                $app.addClass("active");
            }, submitPhase2 - 70);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $login.hide();
                $login.addClass("inactive");
                animating = false;
                $(that).removeClass("success processing");
            }, submitPhase2);
        }, submitPhase1);

    } else {
        alert('Wrong pass!');
    }

});
```

**THE EXACT PROBLEM:**

index.js always generates a 'wrong pass' message. So that means that `if ($('input[pass] .login__input').val() == password) {` is never true. Why is this never true, even when I use "ABCD"?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You're aware that this kind of authentication is just as strong as no authentication at all, right?

Comment: Yes I was. What I wanted to accomplish is a form that would _look_ like authentication, but actually is not. it worked.

Comment: Don't vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because this selector is bad:

```
$('input[pass] .login__input')
```

Here is correct:

```
$('.login__input.pass')
```

Comment: Thanks, you are the MVP!

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
$('input[type=password]')
```

or

```
$('.login__input.pass')
```

as a selector.